# run macro on AutoFilter and show data in new sheet

Tags: excel, autofilter, vba

Actually what i want to do , i have following data With Auto Filtering ,

[image]

->   I want to create new sheet for each unique Name selected from filtering .i.e. if John and Alex are selected then 2 new sheets should be created one for John and second for Alex , and each of them show own data (Name + No + R). When Next time if master sheet get updated then news data should be appended when i run macro. i'm using following code but its not working 100%.

```
Sub mycar()
   x = 2
   Do While Cells(x, 1) <> ""
   If Cells(x, 1) = "John" Then
   Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(x).Copy
   Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
   eRow = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
   ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Rows(eRow)
   End If
   Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
   x = x + 1
   Loop
End Sub
```

-> Here it copy only single data Written in the quotes.

-> Second time if i run this code , it is appending same data again with new data.

Help me to avoid this mistakes.

Thank you.

Comment: This would get you on the right track.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11631363/how-to-copy-a-line-in-excel-using-a-specific-word-and-pasting-to-another-excel-s

Comment: Siddharth thanks for your kind help but actually i want to run macro on auto filter.

Comment: Is it ok for you if you clear Sheet1 and Sheet2 each time you run your macro?? Just before you copy rows there?? Then each time you have complete set of data...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed there is other possibility to set filter parameters in Array in procedure. The code would look like this one:

```
Sub Solution()

Dim shData As Worksheet
    Set shData = Sheets("Arkusz1")    'or other reference to data sheet
Dim shNew As Worksheet
    shData.Activate
'get unique values based on Excel features
Range("a1").AutoFilter

Dim myArr As Variant
    myArr = Array("John", "max")

Range("a1").AutoFilter

Dim i As Long
For i = 0 To UBound(myArr)
    shData.Range("$A$1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=myArr(i), _
        Operator:=xlAnd
On Error Resume Next
    Sheets(myArr(i)).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.ClearContents

If Err.Number = 0 Then
    Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy Sheets(myArr(i)).Range("A1")
Else
    Set shNew = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
    shData.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy shNew.Range("A1")
    shNew.Name = myArr(i)
    Err.Clear
End If

Next i
'removing filter in master sheet
shData.Range("a1").AutoFilter

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Substitute `Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(x).Copy` by `Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(x).EntireRow.Copy`

And clear the destination worksheet before adding information.

Comment: `I want to create new sheet for each unique Name selected from filtering .i.e. if John and Alex are selected then 2 new sheets should be created one for John and second for Alex`  Your code seems to do nothing like what he is asking

Answer (score 0):

I do quite similar exercise quite often. Therefore I provide full possible solution with some comments inside the code. It works for all unique values in column A and creates (if not exists) sheet with appropriate name equals to filter parameters.

```
Sub Solution()
Dim shData As Worksheet
    Set shData = Sheets("Arkusz1")    'or other reference to data sheet
Dim shNew As Worksheet

'get unique values based on Excel features
'i guess some will not like it but I do :)
Range("a1").AutoFilter
Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns(1).Copy Range("ww1")
Range("ww1").CurrentRegion.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
'be sure that range where you copy (like ww1) is empty range around 

Dim myArr As Variant
    myArr = Range(Range("ww2"), Range("ww2").End(xlDown))
Range("ww1").CurrentRegion.ClearContents     'some cleaning
Range("a1").AutoFilter '

Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To UBound(myArr, 1)
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=myArr(i, 1), _
        Operator:=xlAnd
On Error Resume Next
    'this is for two reason- to check if appropriate sheet exists, if so to clean top area
    'if you need to append you would comment this line
    Sheets(myArr(i, 1)).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.ClearContents

If Err.Number = 0 Then
    'if you need to append only you would need to set range-to-copy a bit different
    Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy Sheets(myArr(i, 1)).Range("A1")
Else
    Set shNew = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
    shData.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy shNew.Range("A1")
    shNew.Name = myArr(i, 1)
    Err.Clear
End If

Next i

End Sub
```

This could not fully meet your requirements but could be a complete solution to improve accordingly.

Comment: thanks for your kind help but actually i want to run macro on auto filter.

Comment: you mean that: 1st step you check some names with auto filter, 2nd step run the macro, 3rd- macro creates sheets for each name??

Comment: No dude i have master sheet , macro should be run when i complete selection from AutoFilter , in auto filter if i select John and Max it should copy each of them data from master sheet to new sheet (Sheet2 , Sheet3)

Comment: ok, that is what I mean (sorry for poor English)... So, if you have a lot of data than my 'filtering' solution will be quick. It would require some changes before looping in the code I proposed. See also some comment under your question.

Comment: `ShData` is a sheet where you have batch of your data to autofilter.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27574/discussion-between-ronakmehta-and-kazjaw)

Answer (score 0):

### Heading ##Below code is as per your requirement. Modify it based upon your requirement.

---

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
  Dim x As Integer
  Dim rnge As Integer
  x = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Count
  rnge = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count

  If Range("E1").Value > rnge Then
   Range("A1").Select
   Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
   Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
   Selection.Copy
   Sheets(2).Select
   ActiveSheet.Paste
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Ronik Mehta..you have to modify the above code based upon your requirement.